# Import multiple custom field values from single CSV entry

Tags: php, excel, wpallimport

My data in the database is stored in this format as an array.

The correct way of storing:

```
array (
  0 => '18459',
  1 => '18462',
)
```

The format for importing is separated by a pipe in my csv file like so `18459|18461` but whenever I import, it instead stores the values like this.

```
array (
  0 => '18459|18461',
)
```

[Additional Info] This is how the database stores the data by duplicating the meta key `sp_team`. If I can change the second meta key to something else say sp_team2 then have that in my CSV file I think it might work. The problem is that my import *thinks* it should just import both `18459|18462` into just one `sp_team field` and that the other `sp_team` is not needed which is not the case. But I don't know how.

[image]

Inside the wp-editor for the two fields

[image]
If there was a way I can rename the second `sp_team` that would work?

I am desperate for a workaround. As you can see, it's not storing the second value. I'll appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: So explode on pipe and do an array_merge.

Comment: If you use `fgetcsv()`, there is a parameter to specify what the delimiter is.

Comment: _“The correct way of storing:”_ - meaning what, _exactly_? That exact text you have shown, incuding the word `array` and all? Or something else? _“As you can see”_ - we’re hardly seeing _anything_ … your question so far completely lacks an actual description of _how_ you are doing this import.

Comment: I am importing using wpall import plugin and my csv header is `sp_team`. The data in the cells takes this format `18459|18462` separated by a pipe. When importing like this, the result is `18459|18462` for a single `sp_team` meta key. There are two `sp_team` meta keys, each which should have single values 18459 and 18462 for the other `sp_team` meta key and not `18459|18462` for one `sp_team`. Kindly check image added above in post. If there were separate `sp_team` and say `sp_team2` I think the importer would identify the difference but it doesn't because it *thinks* it's just a duplicate.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on https://www.wpallimport.com/debug and include a link here? I want to see the import settings you're using.

Comment: I have created a sandbox here https://wai-qlrlbylw8a96.wpallimport-demo.qsandbox.me/ I have exported the a file for the events. Take note of the `sp_team` column in the CSV. You will notice the teams are separated by the pipe. Importing the same file back without changing anything doesn't import back properly. I have also left the events in the website untouched for you to see how the teams work. Upon importing the teams are not present as supposed to so that is why I was wondering if that's happening because the teams are sharing the same meta key `sp_team`.

Comment: Thanks - please create an administrator level user so one could log in to /wp-admin :)

Comment: Please login with `admin` and `CJ*or^vB9t` link- https://wai-qlrlbylw8a96.wpallimport-demo.qsandbox.me/wp-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break up the values inside a hook and insert them one by one.

This needs to go into the `functions.php` file of the active theme (or child theme). Commented inline for clarity.

```
function my_18459_update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    $separator = '|';

    // only act on the 2 custom fields with pipes as separators:
    if($meta_key == 'sp_team' || $meta_key == 'sp_player') {

        /* Hook fires AFTER the "incorrect" unseparated meta value was 
           inserted in the DB, so need to delete it first: */
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);

        // break up the values using | as separator:
        $meta_values = explode($separator, $meta_value);
        if ( ! empty( $meta_values ) ) {
            // insert values into wp_postmeta table one by one:
            foreach ( $meta_values as $meta_value ) {
                add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'pmxi_update_post_meta', 'my_18459_update_post_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Screenshots of relevant import settings I used:

[image: screenshot of WP All Import custom fields setting]

[image: screenshot of WP All Import record matching setting]

You can also check the import settings at the link you provided in the comments.

Comment: I tried it on my website and it works! Not sure why it wasn't on the demo site. Appreciated the help.

Comment: Oh the demo site the code is unfinished - it was lacking the `delete_post_meta` part - the service refused to update the functions.php file for some reason. Glad it helped!